# Printing a list of dictionaries as a table

Tags: python-3.x, string, data-manipulation

How can I format the below data into tabular form using Python ?
Is there any way to print/write the data as per the expected format ?

```
[{"itemcode":null,"productname":"PKS543452","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"JHBG6%&9","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"VATER3456","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"ACDFER3434","value_2018":null}]
```

Expected output:

```
|itemcode | Productname | Value_2018 |
|null |PKS543452|null|
|null |JHBG6%&9|null|
|null |VATER3456|null|
|null |ACDFER3434|null|
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified. Without seeing code we do not know where your problem is.

Comment: Hi Patrick ..wanted to understand how to modify list dictionaries using built in methods  , @glhr solution will help ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this as well (without using **pandas**). I have commented each and every line in code itself so don't forget to read them.

> **Note:** Actually, the list/array that you have have pasted is either the result of `json.dumps()` (in Python, a text) or you have copied the API response (JSON).
>
> `null` is from JavaScript and the pasted list/array is not a valid Python list but it can be considered as text and converted back to Python list using `json.loads()`. In this case, `null` will be converted to `None`.
>
> And that's why to form the wanted o/p we need another check like `"null" if d[key] is None else d[key]`.

```
import json

# `null` is used in JavaScript (JSON is JavaScript), so I considered it as string
json_text = """[{"itemcode":null,"productname":"PKS543452","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"JHBG6%&9","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"VATER3456","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"ACDFER3434","value_2018":null}]"""

# Will contain the rows (text)
texts = []

# Converting to original list object, `null`(JavaScript) will transform to `None`(Python)
l = json.loads(json_text)

# Obtain keys (Note that dictionary is an unorederd data type)
# So it is imp to get keys for ordered iteration in all dictionaries of list
# Column may be in different position but related data will be perfect
# If you wish you can hard code the `keys`, here I am getting using `l[0].keys()`
keys = l[0].keys()

# Form header and add to `texts` list
header = '|' + ' | '.join(keys) + " |"
texts.append(header)

# Form body (rows) and append to `texts` list
rows = ['| ' + "|".join(["null" if d[key] is None else d[key] for key in keys]) + "|" for d in l]
texts.extend(rows)

# Print all rows (including header) separated by newline '\n'
answer = '\n'.join(texts)
print(answer)
```

> Output

```
|itemcode | productname | value_2018 |
| null|PKS543452|null|
| null|JHBG6%&9|null|
| null|VATER3456|null|
| null|ACDFER3434|null|
```

Comment: Great Thanks for the detailed summary @hygull

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sleeping, I answered it from mobile but I lost what I wrote, I woke up, started laptop and wrote (page refresh). Anyways, you liked it. Thanks again @shirop.

Comment: How do i maintain a fixed ordering of the keys ? The ordering of the keys is changing with each run.. how can i use OrderedDict in this case to maintain a fixed ordering of keys ? I was trying the below but errored out. l=OrderedDict(json.loads(json_text))   Error - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Yeah, that will is correct. `OrderedDict` takes care of the order of insertions of its items. Here directly we are forming from `json_text` which is again being converted to an unordered dictionary using `json.loads()`. One solution would be to create `OrderedDict` by iterating over a predefined list of keys. And one more thing, `OrderedDict` takes dict objector keyword arguments like `OrderedDict(k=90, l=87)`, not a list .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` to generate a dataframe from the list of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

null = "null"
lst = [{"itemcode":null,"productname":"PKS543452","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"JHBG6%&9","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"VATER3456","value_2018":null},
{"itemcode":null,"productname":"ACDFER3434","value_2018":null}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lst)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  itemcode productname value_2018
0     null   PKS543452       null
1     null    JHBG6%&9       null
2     null   VATER3456       null
3     null  ACDFER3434       null
```

This makes it easy to manipulate data in the table later on. Otherwise, you can print your desired output using built-in string methods:

```
output=[]
col_names = '|' + ' | '.join(lst[0].keys()) + '|' 
print(col_names)

for dic in lst:
    row = '|' + ' | '.join(dic.values()) + '|'
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
|itemcode | productname | value_2018|
|null | PKS543452 | null|
|null | JHBG6%&9 | null|
|null | VATER3456 | null|
|null | ACDFER3434 | null|
```

Comment: Thanks ghlr ... wanted to understand how to manipulate/change  the list dictionary using built in methods. i need to feed the formatted  data as part of the bash command.